# Is a Möbius Strip in > 4 dimensions impossible?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, dimension-theory-analysis, low-dimensional-topology, dimensional-analysis

I seem to remember reading, on a plaque in the math building at Penn State, that Möbius Strips are only possible in 3 and 4 dimensions. In higher dimensional spaces, a Möbius strip will use the extra dimensions to work out its kinks and orient itself.

Is this true? I can't find any discussion of it online.

Comment: That's a fairly vague statement. There is no way for a non-orientable surface to resolve itself into an orientable surface no matter what dimension you embed it in. Do you mean $n$-dimensional analogues to the Mobius strip?

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, nor is math a hobby of mine. Sorry for the vagueness! It is possible that the plaque I saw was referring to _n_-dimensional analogues of the Möbius strip.

Answer (score 4):

This is not true. Obviously, we have an embedding of the Möbius strip into $\mathbb{R}^3$, and there is a rather obvious embedding of $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n \geq 3$ (namely, the map which sends $(x, y, z)$ to $(x, y, z, 0, \ldots, 0)$). The composition of these maps is an embedding of the Möbius strip in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The Möbius strip cannot "work out its kinks" in any space, since it is not homeomorphic to a cylinder.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks! What about _n_-dimensional analogues of the Möbius strip?

Comment: I don't know what an $n$-dimensional analog of the Möbius strip is.